# Polynomial with roots $\alpha-\frac{1}{\beta\gamma}$, $\beta-\frac{1}{\alpha\gamma}$, $\gamma-\frac{1}{\beta\gamma}$ in terms of the roots of a cubic

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations

**QUESTION:**  The equation $x^3+px^2+qx+r=0$ has roots $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Find the equation whose roots are $\alpha - \frac{1}{\beta\gamma} , \beta - \frac{1}{\alpha\gamma} , \gamma - \frac{1}{\alpha\beta} $ .

I tried to solve it by taking the sum of roots, product of roots taken two at a time, and the product of all the roots. I got some equations, could sail some far, but eventually it really messed up and now I am stuck. Can anyone help me out. Is there any other possible way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: We can rewrite the expressions as $\alpha(1-\frac1{\alpha\beta\gamma})$, $\beta(1-\frac1{\alpha\beta\gamma})$, $\gamma(1-\frac1{\alpha\beta\gamma})$

Comment: As a start: take sum the new solutions; you'll find a simple expression of $p$ and $r$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can rewrite the expressions as $\alpha(1-\frac1{\alpha\beta\gamma})$, $\beta(1-\frac1{\alpha\beta\gamma})$, $\gamma(1-\frac1{\alpha\beta\gamma})$.

Or in other words, $\alpha(1+\frac1p)$, $\beta(1+\frac1p)$, $\gamma(1+\frac1p)$.

Let $z=1+\frac1p$. So, the sum of the expressions is $z(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)=-zr$, the sum of product pairs of the expression is $qz^2$, and the product of the expressions is $-pz^3$. So, the polynomial is $$x^3+pz^3x^2+qz^2x+rz$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\dfrac y\alpha=1-(-\dfrac1r)=\dfrac{r+1}r$

$\alpha =\dfrac{yr}{r+1}$

As $\alpha$ is one of the three roots of the given equation,

Replace the value of $\alpha$ in terms of $y$ to find a cubic equation in $y$

It's obvious that we shall reach at the same cubic equation if we start $\beta,\gamma$